# Excel Filter Entire Table with Advance Filtering using Macro with a Cell outside of the Table

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I want to use a Cell with a macro button to Search for a name in an entire table, we have multiple columns so i can't search in only 1. I want it to search as is "contains the name" and not EXACT as cell
Like in the image, if i enter "Test" in G2, i want the filters to get all the row that has the "Test" in it even the one with additional text

[image: Exemple]

When i press the button "device name" filtre from A15 to O15 all get filtered with entry i've put into G2, even if the entry has additionnal text before or after the entry of G2

Comment: You could set up Advanced Filter to do this.  See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not sure how i should use this in a macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an Autofilter example.

I have a data table ("Table2") and above that in E1 a place where a search term can be entered:

[image]

On a separate (could be hidden) sheet "Filter" I have my Advanced Filter criteria range (linked by formula to E1 where the user enters the search term).  Note the headers here match the columns in Table2 which you want to be able to filter on, and each criteria is on a separate row (so this is an "OR" filter).

[image]

Finally a bit of VBA:

```
Range("Table2[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
                  CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Filter").Range("A1:H9"), _
                  Unique:=False
```

Comment: Thank you really much Tim, everything is working perfectly with this!

Comment: Good to hear it was helpful.